# Is there any way to get my laptop's fingerprint scanner to work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/14.10?

Tags: 14.04, windows, hp, 14.10

I currently have a HP Envy Touchsmart 15 notebook PC, and I recently completely switched from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (I'm on 14.10 now though). Anyway, since I switched, my fingerprint scanner on my laptop won't work at all. Which makes sense because of the lack of drivers. But is there any way to get this working again? It's really convenient and I don't want something on my PC that won't even work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Test fingerprint-gui

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run these commands:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
apt-get update
apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Reboot and launch Fingerprint GUI and enroll your fingerprints.

Try locking your screen, logging out and in, sudo in terminal and running graphical apps requiring root privileges.

Troubleshooting: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui

Comment: Thanks so much @kyodake!  It installed perfectly. However, it can't seem to detect my scanner that's built into my PC. Do you know how to fix that? Thanks again.

Comment: you can try the following step: In terminal run "sudo pam-auth-update". Make sure that the PAM profile called “Fingerprint authentication by Fingerprint GUI” is on top of the list and active.

Comment: It is at the top of the list. Whenever I open up Fingerprint GUI all I see is "Validity Sensors, Inc. (0x138a) unknown device (0x50)" which I know is the fingerprinting hardware, but under the "Attached USB Devices" menu. There is nother there for the actual fingerprint device. I just get "No Devices Found!". How do I get it to detect the actual fingerprint device? Thanks for your help, man.